# MYSQL formulating a search query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having slight difficulties (syntax presumably) formulating a query for a search I'm writing in php.

So far I have this:

`$query = ("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field LIKE "$trimmed);`

trimmed is defined as 
`$trimmed = trim($var);`

What I'm trying to accomplish is, use that query to search for a certain row in my mysql database. I've confirmed that it does indeed connect to the dbase and it does grab data from the table. I'm 99% new to php and mysql, I've just started working on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Oh I use the query here:
`$result = mysql_query($query);` I'm sure the issue isn't here, but in $query

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really see a problem here. You're not getting anything? If you use LIKE you probably want to use some operators with that. Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like So do something like: WHERE $field LIKE 'blabla%' to have your search term begin with blabla

Comment: are you using the dot operator after the quotes: $query = ("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field LIKE ".$trimmed);

Comment: Trouble shooting:  start with a simpler method of the query that works, for example use a simple text entry for `$trimmed`.  Work your way up, perhaps gradually, to finished version of SQL.

Comment: Trouble shooting 2:  Test your queries outside of your PHP work, for example using phpMyAdmin.  For more variable-dependent (that is, code-dependent) queries, use a print function to dump out whatever PHP is using for final SQL and then test that in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out the PHP manul](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php), example:

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT data FROM mydb;");
$myarray= array();
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $myarray[] = $row['data'];
}
```

**EDIT**

This is your code? if so, you have a syntax error:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field LIKE "$trimmed);
```

should be:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field LIKE '$trimmed'");
```

Comment: K, so what do you want to know?

Comment: `$query = ("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field LIKE $trimmed");` will fail, as `$trimmed` must be in quotes.

Comment: Cool. If you've just started out with PHP programming I advise you to work with some sort of syntax highlighting program such as eclipse, netbeans or even notepad++. As well, in case you're stuck have a look at the Apache log files, usually located in /var/log/httpd/error_log on Linux or inside the Apache installation under program files.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field LIKE "$trimmed);
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field LIKE '$trimmed'";
```

It's always a good idea to escape any special characters, such as backslash, in the input. With mysql, you can use `mysql_escape_string`:

```
$trimmed = mysql_escape_string($trimmed);
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $field LIKE '$trimmed'";
```

Equivalent commands exist in mysqli, PDO, and all PHP frameworks.